# ListBox - Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, linq-to-xml, windows-store-apps

I am not able to get a listbox to display the result, I could only using "nameInput.Text," I have no idea how to work within a foreach, can anyone help?

C# Code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("biblia.xml");

var pais = 
    from pai in xdoc.Descendants("b")
    where (string)pai.Attribute("indice") == selectedindex.ToString()
    select new
    {
        Filho = pai.Descendants("c")
    };

foreach (var pai in pais) {
    foreach (var filho in pai.Filho) {
        nameInput.Text = nameInput.Text + "     " + filho.Attribute("n");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding filho}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Edit: Here is a part of xml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bible>
  <b n="Gênesis" indice="1">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1"></v>
      <v n="2"></v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1"></v>
      <v n="2"></v>
    </c>
  <b n="Êxodo" indice="2">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1"></v>
      <v n="2"></v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1"></v>
      <v n="2"></v>
    </c>
  </b>
</bible>
```

Edit
I thought the solution was to create a List:

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();

foreach (var pai in pais) {
    foreach (var filho in pai.Filho) {
        MyList.Add(filho.Attribute("n").Value);
    }
}
listBoxTeste1.ItemsSource = MyList;
```

Comment: can you post your XML?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want a ListBox which displays items from your XML file? What are you doing with "nameInput"? It seems unrelated to the ListBox.

Comment: It is a Bible app, after the User choose the book, this part of the code takes the chosen livo and shows how many chapters it has.
example:
Book of Genesis, it shows this result:
n = "1", n = "2", n = "3", n = "4"
I could only do this with text, I need it to be displayed in a ListBox